# LV, Matrix fieldtype with an Assets fieldtype in column

Tags: assets, matrix, low-variables

I have a Low Variable with a Matrix field type. Inside one of the columns I have an Assets field type.

Seems to work on and off. I could load my template, image is displayed. I could refresh the template, I get a 0.

I've tried numerous template tags but I'm not confident its fixed.

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_sidebar_adblock_image"}
<li class="widget"><a href="{link}"><img src="{image:url}"/></a></li>
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

I've also tried this:

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_sidebar_adblock_image"}
<li class="widget"><a href="{link}"><img src="{image}"/></a></li>
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

'image' and 'link' are my Matrix column names. 'image' is the Assets field type.

[image: Screenshot of my LV]

Comment: Sean what version of EE, LV, Matrix, and Assets are you on?

Comment: I'm running the latest version for all 3.

Comment: I've an update though - Since posting the question, this snippet seems to be holding it self together: `code`{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_sidebar_adblock_image"}
<li class="widget"><a href="{link}"><img src="{image:url}"/></a></li>
{/exp:low_variables:parse}`code`

Comment: So this is working now, Sean?

Comment: I'd recommend posting your Answer as a full answer and accepting it. :) Thanks for the update Sean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_sidebar_adblock_image"}
<li class="widget"><a href="{link}"><img src="{image:url}"/></a></li>
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```